# LDAP Fetch Employee ID using PHP

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I am Trying to fetch Employee Id's of users in Active Directory using LDAP PHP. i just added an employee Id field using vb script for users on server and can see the employeeID on AD there.
But when i try to fetch employee id for the same user it doesnot show up whereas rest of the attributes are showing up. Below is my code.
I am new to this.Any help will be appreciated.

```
enter code here

<?php
$partialState =  $_POST['partialState'];


ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

if(!empty($_POST['partialState'])) {
$username1="****";
$password1="*****";
$adServer = "ldap://*******";
$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
$username = $username1;
$password = $password1;
$ldaprdn = '***' . "\\" . $username;
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die ("Could not set      ldap protocol");
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);        


if ($bind) {
echo "binded";

     $dn = "DC=***,DC=**,DC=**" ;


$filter= "(&(objectCategory=person)(displayname=*$partialState*)(employeeID=*))";

$justthese = array("displayname","department" , "title",  "whenCreated","employeeID"); 
$result = ldap_search($ldap,$dn , $filter ,$justthese) or die ("Search failed");


$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
for ($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) { 
echo "Name: ".$info[$i]["displayname"][0]."<br>\n"; 
echo "Department: ".$info[$i]["department"][0]."<br>\n";
echo "Title: ".$info[$i]["title"][0]."<br>\n"; 
echo "EmployeeID: ".$info[$i]["employeeID"][0]."<br>\n";

$date = $info[$i]["whencreated"][0];
// Get the date segments by splitting up the LDAP date
$year = substr($date,0,4);
$month = substr($date,4,2);
$day = substr($date,6,2);
$hour = substr($date,8,2);
$minute = substr($date,10,2);
$second = substr($date,12,2);

// Make the Unix timestamp from the individual parts
$timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);

// Output the finished timestamp
print "Date Created : ".$month."/".$day."/".$year. "\n";


echo "<div class='archievebox'><a href=''>View Details</a></div>";
echo "<hr>"; 
} 
ldap_free_result($result); 
ldap_unbind($ldap); 
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys (attribute-names) in the array returned by ldap_get_entries are all converted to lowercase. So there is no key "employeeID" but "employeeid".

You should be able to see this when you var_dump the returned array.